# drawPie() with customized borders

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

Is it possible to draw a pie shape with no border at the arc, but with borders at straight lines? I have attached a picture below:

Currently I have implemented this by first calling calling `drawPie()` with `painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen)`, and then later using `QLineF` to draw the lines separately based on the center and angles of the pie shape.
[image]

But the problem is that the line position does not sync with the pie shape if the angles are not multiples of 90. Attached another picture showing the problem.

[image]

Is there a simple/elegant way to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your custom Pie is a subclassed QGraphicsRectItem, you could try something like this:

```
class CustomPie(QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem):

    angle = 2000

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):

        # Create the path to draw the lines
        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.moveTo(self.rect().width()/2, self.rect().height()/2)
        path.lineTo(self.rect().width(), self.rect().height()/2)
        path.arcMoveTo(self.rect(), self.angle/16)  # arcMoveTo in degrees
        path.lineTo(self.rect().width()/2, self.rect().height()/2)

        # draw a pie with no Pen
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen))
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.lightGray))
        painter.drawPie(self.rect(), 0, self.angle)

        # Draw the path with a custom Pen
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.black, 2))
        painter.drawPath(path)
```

Here we override `paint` to draw a Pie and a path (actually quite similar to your own method). 
You would have to override `__init__` as well (angle as a class attribute is probably not what you want) but that's the idea.

Comment: Thanks Yoann! I tried your method but I faced the same problem when it comes to angles which are not multiple of 90. I ended up calling drawPie() with a solid brush, and painting a white circle over the outer border using QPainterPath to make it vanish.